# Ошибка PHP: Fatal error: HTTP headers are already sent

Tags: php

> Fatal error: HTTP headers are already sent in /path/to/includes/top.php on line 678. Possibly you have an extra space (or a newline) before the first line of the script or any library. Please note that JsHttpRequest uses its own Content-Type header and fails if this header cannot be set. See header() function documentation for more details in /path/to/includes/classes/JsHttpRequest.php on line 89

Когда нажимаю "оформить заказ" на сайте появляется такая ошибка. Раньше все было нормально, ошибка возникла после переноса на другой хостинг. Что делать?

Comment: не deprecated function?

Comment: нет, написано же - fatal error, при чём тут deprecated?

Answer (score 2):

Предыдущий ответ, конечно, полная ерунда - поскольку, во-первых, сужает все причины появления этой ошибки до единственной, известной автору, а во-вторых, не укладывается в описание проблемы, которая возникла при переносе **тех же самых файлов** на другой хостинг.

Поэтому правильным решением будет переписывание спагетти-говнокода, когда сначала в браузер отправляется какой-то текст, потом НТТР-заголовок, а потом вообще выясняется, что ничего выводить не надо, а надо сделать перенаправление.

В частности, в данном конкретном случае надо сделать так, чтобы файл `top.php` подключался не каждый раз при любом обращении к сайту, а только тогда, когда требуется вывести на экран страницу в дизайне сайта.

Впрочем, я не встречал еще ни одного похапешника, который бы последовал вышеприведённому совету. Им всем столь неимоверных трудов стоит накропать функционал кнопки "оформить заказ", что сама мысль о том, чтобы переписать код и сделать его лучше, приводит их в ужас.

Поэтому единственным приемлемым для себя решением они видят только приведение настроек нового хостинга в соответствие с настройками старого - чтобы новый тоже прощал им кривизну кода. Делается это либо в настройках РНР, путем выставления настройки `output_buffering = on`, либо просто впихиванием в самый верх проблемного скрипта волшебное слово `ob_start()`. Хотя когда я вижу этот второй вариант, то кровавые слёзы льются у меня из глаз. Поскольку использование инструмента не по назначению описал ещё великий Марк Твен, а над незадачливым Томом Кентом, который королевской печатью *орехи колол*, уже сто лет как смеется вся просвещённая Европа.

Answer (score 0):

До боли знакомое =) Заходи на хостинг, открывай этот файл в котором выскакивает данная ошибка (`top.php` или что-то другое). И удали левые символы в самом начале файла (пробелы, кавычки и прочее). Затем нажми "сохранить как..." и убери галочку с  "with BOM".

Т.е. надо сохранить этот файл без BOM-подписи. Из-за неё также выскакивают такие ошибки.